# css3 : how to create 3 flexible columns?

Tags: css

My goal is to create a 3 columns layout:

- 1st  column can take any width : it will change through JS
- 2nd column takes as much space as it can
- 3rd column is width fixed

```css
#red {
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px; /* this can change */
}
#green {
  background-color:green;
    display:inline;
 width:100%; /* this should take ALL the place available */
 
}
#blue {
  background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
 width:200px; /* this is fixed width */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="red">red</div>
    <div id="green">green</div>
    <div id="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Is this possible WITHOUT any JS ?

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox it can be done:

```css
 #container{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   width:100%
}
#red {
  background-color:red;
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis:100px; /* this can change */
  word-wrap: break-word
}
#green {
  background-color:green;
  flex-grow:1 /* this should take ALL the place available */
 
}
#blue {
  background-color:blue;
  flex-grow:0;
  flex-basis:200px; /* this is fixed width */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="red">redredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredredred</div>
    <div id="green">green</div>
    <div id="blue">blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Infact , problem is when $("#red").text("put some long"); it will add multi line

Comment: it will if you add `word-wrap: break-word`, otherwise not

Comment: But how to make the RED resize automatically when text content grows ?

Comment: I edited the answer, if you set `flex-grow:1` it will scale (if there's enough space),

Comment: It is ALMOST good, but flex-grow:1 TAKES TOO MUCH space now : it should take the minimum of space so text is not cut: is there a solution for that ?

Comment: if you set it to 0 it will always remain the size of flex-basis ,it won't grow in proportion with flexbox // if you appreciate my help accept and vote

Answer (score 0):

I would use display table.
IE8+ compatible.

```css
#container {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
    
    #red {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
    }

    #blue {
        display: table-cell;
        background: blue;
    }

    #green {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100px;
        background: green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Infact , problem is when $("#red").text("put some long"); it will add multi line